# Python - Printing arrays using For Loop

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have a multiple 2D arrays with name temp1, temp2, temp3... etc

```
temp1 = [[7, 2, 4],
         [5, 0, 6],
         [8, 3, 1]] 

temp2 = [[1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1]] 

temp3 = [[2, 2, 2],
         [2, 2, 2],
         [2, 2, 2]]
```

I want to run a **for loop** that will return only some of the arrays depending on the **range of i**. I am thinking of something like

```
for i in range(1,3):
    arrayName = ("temp" + str(i))
    print(arrayName)
```

where **print(arrayName)** prints out the actual array instead of a string

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with `exec()`. Also your `range()` should have an upper bound of your max value plus one. The upper bound is not inclusive.

```py
for i in range(1, 4):
    exec(f'print(temp{str(i)})')
```

Output:

```py
[[7, 2, 4], [5, 0, 6], [8, 3, 1]]
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
[[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval()`. It allows you to get a variable by name.

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    current_array = eval(f'temp{i}')
    print(current_array)
```

But, I advise you to set this part of code to the try/except block because you can have NameError exception. And your code will look like:

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    variable_name = f"temp{i}"

    try:
        current_array = eval(variable_name)
        print(current_array)
    except NameError:
        print(f"Can not get variable with {variable_name} name")
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice that this is your requirement:

> ... where print(arrayName) prints out the actual array instead of a string

If so, you could use the following simplified design pattern:

```
arrays = [array1, array2, array3]
for array in arrays: 
    print(array)
```

And, in modification of your code, so that print() will 'print out the actual array instead of a string':

```
temp1 = [[7, 2, 4],
         [5, 0, 6],
         [8, 3, 1]]

temp2 = [[1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1]]

temp3 = [[2, 2, 2],
         [2, 2, 2],
         [2, 2, 2]]

temps = [temp1, temp2, temp3]

for i in temps:
    print(i)
```

Some further thoughts:

1. I would avoid the eval() or exec() Python methods as suggested by the other commenters. Simpler solutions are possible; you do not have a concrete reason to use dynamic execution.
2. There is a cleaner way to refactor your code, but I am providing the above  answer that mirrors your code structure more directly so as to avoid confusion.